# Eclipse breakpoints specific for each Project?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I am working in Eclipse Helios, Mac OS X last Leopard, with several projects at the same time. I set breakpoints in project 1 and fine. Project 2 is a fork of Project 1 so contains similar files. When I try to debug Project 2, the debugger stops at the same breakpoints that are defined for Project 1, how can this be? How can I make breakpoints specific for each Project?

Comment: A workaround is to close all unrelated opened projects, but this is not elegant, as I need to have a look at the other projects. Maybe I will try to open different instances of Eclipse with the different Projects.

Comment: Seeing the same behavior. Has to be an Eclipse bug!

Comment: yes, another one to the list of 10000 bugs

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a conditional breakpoint whose condition is true for only one of the projects.

In Eclipse, you can set a conditional breakpoint by:

- Right-clicking on the breakpoint
- Choosing "Breakpoint Properties"
- On the first page, clicking the "Conditional" checkbox and adding in the box below a condition (a Java boolean expression).

Comment: `Condition`? Give an example.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK - One example would be to set a property in one of the two launchers, and check in the condition whether the property is set.

Answer (score -1):

Often a solution is simply to let Eclipse know which of the two projects you are stepping through: in the debug view, select an entry from the stack of that specific project.